# Changing color in \newcommand

Tags: macros, color, cv, resume

I used LaTeX several years ago to make my resume. I have updated it sometimes with minor adjustments.

I am starting at a consultancy firm soon and they wanted a blue theme. I was going to change the section headers into blue but I am not successful. The code is:

```
\newcommand{\NewPart}[1]{\section*{\uppercase{#1}}}

\NewPart{Personal details}
\NewPart{Work experience}
```

I want personal details, work experience etc to be written in the color RoyalBlue using the xcolor package. I guess it can be inserted in the NewPart code somehow? Thankful for help!

Comment: \usepackage{xcolor} is inserted fyi

Comment: Welcome to TeX:SE! It will be helpful, if you would extend your code fragment to complete small document.

Answer (score 2):

When giving us code, try always to give a complete but minimal example so we know what documentclass, etc., you're using.

The following works, however:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\NewPart}[1]{\section*{\textcolor{RoyalBlue}{\uppercase{#1}}}}

\NewPart{Personal details}
Some details

\NewPart{Work experience}
Some other stuff

\end{document}
```

Comment: Frabjous, thank you very much for your clear and concise answer which solved my problems! I understand your feedback regarding the code, I will look at other posts for guidance if I submit another query. Thanks again and have a nice evening, /Karl

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what is purpose to define new command with functionality of `section` command. Isn't it easier to redefine `section style, for example by use of` titlesec` package:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
 {\Large\sffamily\bfseries\color{RoyalBlue}}
 {\thesection.}
 {1em}
 {}
 

\usepackage{lipsum} 

\begin{document} 
\section{RoyalBlue}
\lipsum[1] 
\section{Test}
\lipsum[2]
\section{Last section}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]